# Python StatsModels: ValueError: Expected frequency D. Got M

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, statsmodels, pandas-resample

I am using `statsmodels.graphics` to draw a `month_plot` from timeseries data in a [kaggle dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/robikscube/hourly-energy-consumption?select=DOM_hourly.csv). I have converted the data to daily frequency mean data as required for the plot. However, I am getting an error that says `the expected data frequency is D, but the actual data frequency is M` where as my actual data is already D.

```
import pandas as pd
from statsmodels.graphics.tsaplots import month_plot
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('/kaggle/input/hourly-energy-consumption/DOM_hourly.csv')
df.set_index('Datetime', inplace=True, drop=True)
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
# drop duplicated index
df = df[~df.index.duplicated(keep='first')]

# convert df to daily mean frequency dataframe
ddf = df.resample(rule='24H', kind='interval').mean().to_period('d')

# print example dataframe ddf
#
#                 DOM_MW
# Datetime  
# 2005-05-01    7812.347826
# 2005-05-02    8608.083333
# ...         ...
# 2017-12-30    14079.125000
# 2017-12-31    15872.833333

# Monthly plot from the Daily frequency data
plt.figure(figsize=(14,4))
month_plot(ddf)
plt.show()
```

Present output: As you can see above, my `ddf` is clearly a daily frequency data. But I am getting following weird error saying my `ddf` data is actually M (Monthly) but it expects D (Daily).

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-675f2911920c> in <module>
      7 
      8 plt.figure(figsize=(14,4))
----> 9 month_plot(ddf)
     10 plt.show()

ValueError: Expected frequency D. Got M
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to use `month_plot` to plot daily data. If you want to use `month_plot`, you have to resample your data first:

```
>>> help(month_plot)
...
    x : array_like
        Seasonal data to plot. If dates is None, x must be a pandas object
        with a PeriodIndex or DatetimeIndex with a **monthly frequency**.
...
```

```
month_plot(ddf.resample('M').mean())
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: You are spot on. I appreciate you a lot for going extra mile to see the cause and correct my knowledge about. I over read it and was wrong. I thought it to be Daily but I have to feed monthly frequency data. Now I understood: it actually plotting all years  january month data in the Jan label and showing a mean in the red line.

Comment: I got stuck here for two days, could not  move an inch. Thinking what could be wrong. But you are a gem and thanks a lot. People like you make SF a truly humane (helping others but not knowing whom you are helping). This is really good place to be with. No more comments. Thanks again.